# Is it possible to implement a read-modify-write cycle in Redis?

Tags: c#, .net, redis

Trying to access a Redis `Key` from C# using ***StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.AspNetCore*** client library, the problem at hand is that this `key` must be change only by ***One*** client.

The `key` has a value of `0` and has to be changed to `1`, but only the client that read the `0`, when writing the `1` is the ***One*** that get the control.

Is the same semaphore schema implemented in many languages, but this is for multiple clients to get control for some resource until it is released by writing a `0` again.

The use case is multiple clients from different locations race to issue an atomic `read-modify-write` to the `key` writing a `1`, but only ***One*** (the first) reads the `0` (or none if already a previous client has it) and the rest reads the modified `1`.

Has anyone solve a problem like this using Redis, is there a way to solve it or a library that implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Lua script to implement "read and update".

Here is a sample for Lua:

```
if redis.call("get", KEYS[1]) == ARGV[1] then
    redis.call("set", KEYS[1], ARGV[2])
    return 1
else
    return 0
end
```

And you can use return value to determine if the client get control.

Comment: But what happens if two clients execute this script at the same time and: 
both execute the `first line` before any of them execute the `second one`, the atomic requirement it not accomplished because the first call is not tied with the second.

Comment: Unless this script run inside the Redis server, and the server guarantee that only one script is running at a time. Imagine 100 clients executing this at the same time some of them will get the `0` if that guarantee is not provided, but at script level this generates a huge performance penalty, that is the reason why a `read-modify-write` atomic operation exits in many systems (and hardware implemented at instruction level in CPU's).  We will try to test your proposal to verify it.

Comment: This are the results: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-guide-to-redis-lua-scripting/ 
All steps within a script are executed in an atomic way. 
No other Redis command can run while a script is executing.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/9012649/gawain solution is perfect most of the time and is a good use of the lua system. Effectively, a lua script executes in an atomic way (since redis is single threaded and handles 1 request at a time).

However, when the size of the data is significant (the redis request includes 2 copies) and/or the collision potential is important performance may be an issue. A solution may be to include some form of mutex in the data set and use the lua script to manage that small data piece. This work well if the value is a json object (rejson) and the mutex is some high level key.